# SilverlightJavascript loop through childrens of an element

Tags: javascript, silverlight-4.0

I have this setup in my xml

```
  <Grid x:Name="Vakken" Visibility="Collapsed">
     <TextBlock Text="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
     <TextBlock Text="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
     <TextBlock Text="3" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
     <TextBlock Text="4" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
     <TextBlock Text="5" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
     <TextBlock Text="6" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
     <TextBlock Text="7" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
     <TextBlock Text="8" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
  </Grid>
```

and what i'm trying to do is loop through all the elements of `Grid`

```
classViewPage = document.getElementById('SchermPage');
gridElements = classViewPage.content.findName('Vakken').children;
for (var i = 0; i < gridElements.count; i++) {
        vakkenNamen += gridElements.children[i];
}
```

i already tried this but it doesn't work. It stops once i try to get an element with `[i]`.

The count itself works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access an array element, you don't need the dot after `children`:

```
vakkenNamen += vakkenElementen.children[i];
```

You also haven't defined `vakkenElementen`, have you? You should store it in a variable:

```
var vakkenElementen= classViewPage.content.findName('Vakken');
gridElements = vakkenElementen.children;
```

After you did this, the code should work as expected.

*Edit: Changed `vakkenNamen` to `vakkenElementen` according to OP's edit.*

**Edit:** Another edit of the question, considering this, this loop should work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gridElements.count; i++) {
        vakkenNamen += gridElements[i];
}
```

Comment: Srr was just a typo but that isn't the problem

Comment: Srr but the vakkenElementen was supposed to be gridElements

Comment: @Kupi Consider my last edit. `gridElements` already contains the children of `Vakken`, no need to use `children` in the loop again.

Comment: @Kupi Please define "not working". What error message do you get?

Comment: When i try to get something with the []. I now tried to alert the text of the first element before the loop but it gives error so the error is not in the loop. this is what i get.

Unhandled exception at line 14, column 5 in http://localhost:1971/Javascript/Scherm.js

0x80004005 - Runtime-fout JavaScript: unknown exception

Answer (score 0):

try this. i think you had a sytax error you didnt need the extra '.'
i.e. your code was

```
vakkenNamen += vakkenElementen.children.[i];
```

you actually need

```
vakkenNamen += vakkenElementen.children[i];
```

full code:

```
classViewPage = document.getElementById('SchermPage');
gridElements = classViewPage.content.findName('Vakken').children;
for (var i = 0; i < gridElements.count; i++) {
        vakkenNamen += vakkenElementen.children[i];
}
```

also is `vakkenNamen` even defined?